# Create lightmap baking using custom UV/texture coordinates in Xcode's SceneKit editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, 3d, rendering, scenekit

Im trying to bake light map texture for my models in Xcode's SceneKit editor. But it's not generating the texture based on my uv coordinates. Is there a way to specify the texture coordinates for Xcode to use?

I tried to do it with a simple rounded box. This is the result:

#### Import Collada model

I import the model with a single UV/texture coordinate source. The preview of it looks correct, as you can see below.

[image]

#### Bake the lightmap

When I then try to bake the lightmap to a texture, it creates new UV/texture coordinates with a corresponding texture. But this a different texture layout/texture coordinates (as you can see in the preview below). As you can see, the quality is not that great either, you can see a light gray square on the side. On the real models I'm testing on it looks MUCH worse, and everything looks like it's placed incorrectly.

[image]

This is what the texture looks like.

[image]

---

**So is there any way to have it generate the texture using provided UV/texture coordinates?** Or how I'm a supposed to use this?

Comment: What `UV Texture Editor` have you used (in what app)?

Comment: @ARGeo They are exported from Maya, using the OpenCollada exporter, which I think an Apple engineer recommended here on SO.

Comment: You might be the first person to try to use their light baking. This might be a bug.